# Resolving name conflicts in references in Sphinx with intersphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, cross-reference

I am writing docs for my python library Using sphinx, I also added another sphinx documentation with intersphinx. And it works pretty nice, but a few my functions are named the same as in referenced documentation, which leads to shadowing their names for `:func:...` referencing.

Is there any way I can reference shadowed function `do_some()` in other documentation? 
(`` :func:`do_some` `` creates a link to my function `do_some()`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/ext/intersphinx.html#confval-intersphinx_mapping) you can use the identifier from your `intersphinx_mapping` as
a prefix to the target. Example:

```
:ref:`comparison manual <python:comparisons>`
```

I think this should work with work with functions too.

Comment: Thanks, that helped, I used `:func:\`python:do_some\`` and it worked